# How can we implement Check Spelling button functionality which is in case object in a visualforce page.?

Tags: visualforce

I have tried using visualforce page but i can't get check spelling button functionality. May I know how to use that functionality in visualforce page.

Answer (score 1):

Google for and choose a JavaScript spell checker. One example is [JavaScript SpellCheck](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JQuery_SpellCheck_Plugin) that has the advantage of building on jQuery that is commonly used in Visualforce pages.